# Is there a way of drawing a line of any length between points without resorting to complicated arithmetic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, points

I am looking for something like

```
pointA to pointB, length
```

where `pointA` is starting point, `pointB` is ending point, and `length` is a line length spanning from starting to ending point.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary
    {%
        positioning,
        shapes.geometric
    }

% FOLLOWING STYLES ARE NOT IMPORTANT AND CAN BE SKIMMED THROUGH;
\tikzset
    {%
        TRIANGLE/.style=
            {%
                isosceles triangle,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                minimum size=30mm,
                shape border rotate=270,
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                line width=2mm,
                draw
            },
        LINE/.style=
            {%
                line width=2mm,
                draw=red
            }
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[TRIANGLE](T){};
        \path[LINE]
            % FOLLOWING COORDINATES SHOULD SERVE AS POINTS
            %  BETWEEN WHICH A LINE OF ANY SPECIFIED LENGTH CAN BE DRAWN,
            %  NOT OF A FIXED LENGTH SPANNING FROM ONE POINT TO ANOTHER (LIKE IN THIS EXAMPLE);
            % IT CAN BE DONE USING COMPLICATED ARITHMETIC
            %  BUT ARE THERE ANY MEANS IN PGF (OR ELSE) TO MAKE IT SIMPLER?
            (T.right corner)--(T.left side);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output (green line is where the red line should stop):

[image]

Comment: yes, tikz has a `calc`  library and then you can use `\draw (a) -- ($(a)!length!(b)$);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calc` library can do that.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary
    {%
        calc,
        positioning,
        shapes.geometric
    }

% FOLLOWING STYLES ARE NOT IMPORTANT AND CAN BE SKIMMED THROUGH;
\tikzset
    {%
        TRIANGLE/.style=
            {%
                isosceles triangle,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
                minimum size=30mm,
                shape border rotate=270,
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                line width=2mm,
                draw
            },
        LINE/.style=
            {%
                line width=2mm,
                draw=red
            }
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[TRIANGLE](T){};
        \path[LINE]
            % FOLLOWING COORDINATES SHOULD SERVE AS POINTS
            %  BETWEEN WHICH A LINE OF ANY SPECIFIED LENGTH CAN BE DRAWN,
            %  NOT OF A FIXED LENGTH SPANNING FROM ONE POINT TO ANOTHER (LIKE IN THIS EXAMPLE);
            % IT CAN BE DONE USING COMPLICATED ARITHMETIC
            %  BUT ARE THERE ANY MEANS IN PGF (OR ELSE) TO MAKE IT SIMPLER?
            ($(T.right corner)!.3!(T.left side)$)--(T.left side);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 You can read about it in [section 13.5.3 of the manual](http://mirror.aut.ac.nz/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#subsubsection.13.5.3).